# How can I detect the mime type with PHP when an actual file doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mime-types

Is there a way to detect the mime type of a file without actually having an actual file, for example when you're generating the file and serving it as a download?

I'm currently using file extension sniffing from here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#87856

I was just wondering if there was another way short of actually creating the file on the server and using FileInfo, mime_content_type(), or `file`

Comment: If you're generating the file, shouldn't you already know what the mime type is?

Comment: @Marc - agreed. Sort of a mysterious question here.

Comment: Yes, I should already know the mime type. I'm just being lazy, and don't feel like having to look up the mime type each time I create a file download. 
As in doing something like:
`echo output_file($filename, $content); exit;`
where output_file would handle all the headers for me.

Comment: I don't get it either. How many different file types could you possibly generate yourself that you can't keep track of what file type you're generating...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) `finfo_buffer()` function:

```
$filename = 'image.jpg';
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
var_dump( finfo_buffer($finfo, $contents) ); // string(10) "image/jpeg"
```

You do say "short of actually creating the file," so this seems to meet your requirements even though it uses Fileinfo.

Comment: Ah! I can't beleive I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of file you're generating, just consult an array of known mime types and apply as appropriate.

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that this is the method I'm currently using. I'm wondering if there was a more reliable way, and one that I don't have to maintain myself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pipe it as such:

```
 $type = `echo $FILE_CONTENTS | file -bi -`
```

READ: This is a bad idea. Do not do this. 'Command line injection' (thanks to Andrew Moore for point this out.)

Comment: ...but the file doesn't exist (mysteriously).

Comment: Yes Steve, and this approach doesn't require it to be... What is your point?

Comment: You don't need the actual file for this method. All you need is the file contents in $FILE_CONTENTS. Or is it that you don't have the file OR the file contents. What do you have then? Now I'm confused too.

Comment: -1: That's a terrible idea. Ever heard of command line injection?

Comment: Oh yeah. I guess that calls for an 'oops'.

Comment: For the sake of discussion, won't it be safer to just escape the contents and then send it or would that defeat the whole purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing it to a ramdisk - shouldn't have a significant speed penalty and you can use the standard functions

Answer (score 0):

you can check this :

```
 $filename = 'image.jpg'; 
 $filename2 = 'file.php'; 
 echo mime_content_type($filename) . "<br>";
 echo mime_content_type($filename2);
```